# Expand/Collapse Menu not working at all

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

I am trying to cretae an expand/collapse menu using javascript. The structure something  like this.

```
.menu
   .subItem
   .subItem
```

this a part of css

```
ul.menu {
    display: none
}
```

but menu items not expandind  from the collapse

this the js file

```
window.onload = initAll;

function initAll() {
    var allLink = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i = 0; i < allLink.length; i++) {
        if (allLink[i].className.indexOf("menuLink") > -1) {

            allLink[i].onclick = togle;
        }

    }
}

function togle() {
    var startMenu = this.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
    var stopMenu = this.href.lastIndexOf(".");
    var thisMenuName = this.href.substring(startMenu, stopMenu);

    var thisMenu = document.getElementById(thisMenuName).style;

    if (thisMenu.display == "block") {
        thisMenu.display = "none";
    } else {
        thisMenu.display = "block";
    }
    return false;
}
```

when I open up chrome developer tools I have realize that Its been pointed out 
this line once click the menu

```
var thisMenu = document.getElementById(thisMenuName).style;
```

What am doing wrong again again again

@Edit:I  forgot to add html  file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
<script src="js.js"></script>

a
</head>
<body>
 <div>
 <a href="" class="menuLink">trajedi</a>
<ul class="menu" id="menu1">
<li><a href="">deneme</a></li>
<li><a href="">deneme</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what you tried to do with the substring part in togle function. That's the only problem with your code. Change the line:

```
var thisMenu = document.getElementById(thisMenuName).style;
```

to

```
var thisMenu = document.getElementById('menu1').style;
```

and it will work. Take a look:

```js
    window.onload = initAll;
    
    function initAll() {
        var allLink = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
        for (var i = 0; i < allLink.length; i++) {
            if (allLink[i].className.indexOf("menuLink") > -1) {    
                allLink[i].onclick = togle;
            }        
        }
    }
    
    function togle(e) {
        // can't understand the use of the 3 lines below:
        var startMenu = this.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
        var stopMenu = this.href.lastIndexOf(".");
        var thisMenuName = this.href.substring(startMenu, stopMenu);

        var thisMenu = document.getElementById('menu1').style;
    
        if (thisMenu.display == "block") {
            thisMenu.display = "none";
        } else {
            thisMenu.display = "block";
        }
        return false;
    }
```

```css
    ul.menu {
        display: none
    }
```

```html
<div>
    <a href="" class="menuLink">trajedi</a>
    <ul class="menu" id="menu1">
      <li><a href="">deneme</a></li>
      <li><a href="">deneme</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

a much simpler and modern version of your code would be:

```js
function initAll() {    
    Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("a"))
        .filter((link)=>link.className.indexOf("menuLink") > -1)
        .forEach((link)=>link.onclick = ()=>{
            var thisMenu = document.getElementById('menu1').style;
            thisMenu.display = (thisMenu.display == "block") ? 'none' : 'block';
            return false;
        });
}
window.onload = initAll;
```

```css
ul.menu {
        display: none
    }
```

```html
<div>
    <a href="" class="menuLink">trajedi</a>
    <ul class="menu" id="menu1">
      <li><a href="">deneme</a></li>
      <li><a href="">deneme</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: one more question since I am a new be I dont know how to add this run snippets  thing.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to complete the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the help topic [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting. Good questions normally have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, StackOverflow has an [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) with lots of information. Thanks.

Comment: When you write a question or an answer there is a small paper sheet icon with <> inside just right to the image icon. This is where you access the snippet interface.